# CALCULATE PERCENTAGE IN SQL by group

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I pulled out data from a database like this (simplified for the sake of simplicity), I'd like to add a column called "percentage".

```
ID   GRADE   PERCENTAGE
 1     10        10/(10+20) * 100 -- THIS PART SHOULD BE SHOWN IN DIGIT
 1     20           .
 2     15           15/(15+24+16) * 100
 2     24
 2     16
 3     29
 4     96
 4     159
 .     .
 .     .
 .     .
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner select gets the `garde` sum of the `id`s.

```
select t.id, t.grade, t.grade * 100 / gsum
from your_table t
join
(
   select id, sum(grade) as gsum
   from your_table
   group by id
) tmp on tmp.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the OVER(PARTITION BY ), you won't need a join in SQL Server

```
SELECT *,  100*Grade/ SUM(Grade) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS Percentage
FROM (
     VALUES(1, 10),(1,20), (2, 15), (2,24), (2,16), (3,29)
) your_table (ID, GRADE)
```

Comment: I have like milion rows. That'd be impossible to type all their values.

Comment: It is example data.
You can just do `FROM your_table` (replace line `2` onwards)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.ID,
       t1.GRADE,
       100.0 * (t1.GRADE / t2.gradeSum) AS PERCENTAGE   -- important: multiply
FROM yourTable t1                                       -- by 100.0 here
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, SUM(GRADE) AS gradeSum
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY ID
) t2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
a.id, a.grade
, case
    when b.total = 0 then 0
    else a.grade/b.grade * 100
  end as percentage
from
data a
cross apply (
   select sum(tot.grade) as total
   from data tot where a.id = tot.id
) b
```